# Function executes normally but addeventlistener won't execute function

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I am trying to sort a js object when clicked on a button.

function work when called normally but doesn't work when added to an eventlistener.

What's wrong? (Can't put it in jsfiddle, too big of a file, sorry)

```
var productData = TABLE_DATA;

const sortButton = document.querySelector("#sort");
sortButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  productData = productData.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.id - b.id;
  });
});



for (let i = 0; i < productData.length; i++) {
  const id = productData[i].id;
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createTextNode(id);
  p.appendChild(text);
  document.querySelector("#productId").appendChild(p);
}
```

It works when called like this:

```
function name() {
    productData = productData.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.id - b.id;
      });
}
name()
```

Comment: Your function correctly does sort the `productData`. It just never renders the updated array, so you don't see the new order in the page.

Comment: Try using useState for productData array